# Referring to a different table's cell value in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

I'm doing some code estimating and have split my project up like so

```
* Overview


| Proposal        | Best case                                    | Likely case                                    | Worst case | Average |
|-----------------+----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+------------+---------|
| First proposal  | (Best case total from first proposal table)  | (Likely case total from first proposal table)  | etc        |         |
| Second proposal | (best case total from second proposal table) | (Likely case total from second proposal table) | etc        |         |
#+TBLFM: $5=vmean($2..$4);%0.2f

** First proposal

| Section | Best case | Likely case | Worst case | Average |
|---------+-----------+-------------+------------+---------|
| Foo     |         1 |           2 |          3 |    2.00 |
| Bar     |         2 |           3 |          2 |    2.33 |
| Baz     |         1 |           1 |          1 |    1.00 |
|---------+-----------+-------------+------------+---------|
| Total   |         4 |           6 |          6 |    5.33 |
#+TBLFM: $5=vmean($2..$4);%0.2f::@5$2=vsum(@2..@-1)::@5$3=vsum(@2..@-1)::@5$4=vsum(@2..@-1)


** Second proposal 

| Section | Best case | Likely case | Worst case | Average |
|---------+-----------+-------------+------------+---------|
| Foo     |         1 |           2 |          3 |    2.00 |
| Bar     |         2 |           3 |          2 |    2.33 |
| Baz     |         4 |           5 |          8 |    5.67 |
|---------+-----------+-------------+------------+---------|
| Totals  |         7 |          10 |         13 |   10.00 |
#+TBLFM: $5=vmean($2..$4);%0.2f::@5$2=vsum(@2..@-1)::@5$3=vsum(@2..@-1)::@5$4=vsum(@2..@-1)
```

Is it possible to get org-mode to automatically copy the total values from the other tables so I don't have to do it manually as I add/edit rows?

Comment: I guess I could put them all in the same table with horizontal separators, but that makes it look a bit muddy (imo)

Comment: Copy the values from which other tables to where? It's not clear to me what you are asking.

Comment: I've edited it to make it clearer - I'm trying to copy the First proposal's Best Case Total to the First Proposal Best Case cell in the first table, and similar for the rest of the cells in the top table

Comment: I think it's possible: you have to name the tables so you can refer to them remotely and then use [remote references](https://orgmode.org/manual/References.html#index-remote-references).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [remote references](https://orgmode.org/manual/References.html#index-remote-references) for this task. Essentially, they note that the reference (e.g. `@5$2`) shouldn't looked up in the current table, but in a foreign one. You only need a `#+NAME` to refer to other tables:

```
** First proposal 

#+NAME: First proposal
| Section | Best case | Likely case | Worst case | Average |
|---------+-----------+-------------+------------+---------|
| Foo     |         1 |           2 |          3 |    2.00 |
| Bar     |         2 |           3 |          2 |    2.33 |
| Baz     |         1 |           1 |          1 |    1.00 |
|---------+-----------+-------------+------------+---------|
| Total   |         4 |           6 |          6 |    5.00 |
#+TBLFM: $>=vmean($2..$>>);%0.2f :: @>$2..@>$>>=vsum(@I..II)
```

The calculation of the sums on the last row has also been simplified to avoid duplication, by using a `range`: the cells on the last row (`@>`) from column 2 (`$2`) to the penultimate column (`$>>`); in each column, the sum ranges over the values from the first horizontal separator to the second horizontal separator (`@I..II`).

```
** Second proposal 

#+NAME: Second proposal
| Section | Best case | Likely case | Worst case | Average |
|---------+-----------+-------------+------------+---------|
| Foo     |         1 |           2 |          3 |    2.00 |
| Bar     |         2 |           3 |          2 |    2.33 |
| Baz     |         4 |           5 |          8 |    5.67 |
|---------+-----------+-------------+------------+---------|
| Totals  |         7 |          10 |         13 |   10.00 |
#+TBLFM: $>=vmean($2..$>>);%0.2f :: @>$2..@>$>>=vsum(@I..II)
```

Now it's possible to use `remote(First proposal, @>$2)` to refer to the first proposal's best case total. However, since the name of the remote table is already in the first column of your target table, we can instead use `remote($1, ...)` to get rid of duplicate code:

```
* Overview

| Proposal        | Best case | Likely case | Worst case | Average |
|-----------------+-----------+-------------+------------+---------|
| First proposal  |           |             |            |         |
| Second proposal |           |             |            |         |
#+TBLFM: $2=remote($1, @>$2)::$3=remote($1,@>$3)::$4=remote($1,@>$4)::$5=vmean($2..$4);%0.2f
```

We can simplify this even further and just fill our current column with the last value in the column of the other table:

```
| Proposal        | Best case | Likely case | Worst case | Average |
|-----------------+-----------+-------------+------------+---------|
| First proposal  |           |             |            |         |
| Second proposal |           |             |            |         |
#+TBLFM: @2$2..@>$>>=remote($1, @>$$#) :: $> = vmean($2..$>>);%0.2f
```

`@2$2..@>$>>` are all fields in the rectangular region from the second row, second column cell to the cell in the last row and the penultimate column; `remote($1, @>$$#)` then looks up a value in the last row (`@>`) but the same column (`$$#`) in the given table. The last column is recalculated from the other columns in the same way as in the other tables, in order to apply the "two digits after the decimal point" format.

Comment: Very nice! You might want to simplify the formulas for the totals in the two original tables: instead of calculating each one, you can use a range formula assignment, e.g `@>$2..@>$>> = vsum(@I..II)` - in words, the range of cells on the last row, columns 2 to the one before the last is set to the sum of all elements in the  corresponding column, between the first and second separators. Unfortunately, I don't think that the column-by-column copying can be shortened in the overview table (but I'd be delighted if I were wrong).

Comment: @NickD Well, let me surprise you: `#+TBLFM: @<<$<<..$>=remote($1, @>$$#)` ;). Great ideas, by the way, it was fun to come up with that table formula :)

Comment: Thanks! That's very nice indeed, but I've already +1'd your answer, so I cannot do it again :-) Glad you had fun.

Comment: I hope you don't mind but I would like to edit your answer to incorporate the comments and modify your last TBLFM line to make it clearer (at least IMO). If you don't like the edits, feel free to revert.

Comment: This is great! Updating all of the org files to use this is going to make my life much easier :-)

Comment: Though actually that last table formula doesn't work for me on emacs 24.5.1 - the debugger gives me Substitution history of formula
Orig:   remote($1, (@>$$#))
$xyz->  remote($1, (@>$$#))
@r$c->  remote($1, (@>$2))
$1->    remote((Do nothing), (@>(0)))
        ----------------------^
Error:  Expected a number

Comment: Having now looked into it, it looks like my version of org-mode will replace a reference with the value in the current table, instead of it being kept as a reference so I've taken inspiration from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673987/org-mode-spreadsheet-programmatic-remote-references and used '(org-table-get-remote-range $2 (string ?@ ?> ?$ ?$#)) which is a bit of a cop-out but does at least work.